# getDuration function in mediaplayer android

Tags: android

I'm developing android application using Mediaplayer class that plays a song using a url. The problem is that the returned value after calling

```
mp.getDuration()
```

is larger than the actual duration of the song.
for example the song has a duration of 4.3 but in my application it gives that it equals 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details about your working environment (android version, file format, ...)?

The MediaPlayer is quite buggy. Surely you are experiencing one bug regarding some specific format. Have a look to the [open issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=MediaPlayer.getDuration%28%29&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&cells=tiles) in this topic.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned ..  it is android

Comment: I mean which API level you are targeting (for example, level 8 correspond to Android 2.2) and which audio format you are trying to play (mp3, wav, ..). Depending on these parameters you could be experiencing some bug.

Comment: Could you try with a mp3 file with sample rate 44,100 Hz? In the issue I link below, they suggest that problems related with wrong returned values for getDuration() are related with the sample rate of the audio file. [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2559&q=getduration%20mp3&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)